# Why we can't use "simpl" on `j = j -> x = y`?

Tags: coq

I am trying to solve the `injection_ex3` exercise in Software Foundation Volume 1.

I have the following prove

```
Example injection_ex3 : forall (X : Type) (x y z : X) (l j : list X),
  x :: y :: l = z :: j ->
  j = z :: l ->
  x = y.
Proof.
  intros t x y z l j.
  intros H1 H2.
  injection H1 as Hnm1.
  assert (H3: z :: j = z :: z :: l).
  replace j with (z :: l).
  reflexivity.
  injection H3.
  rewrite <- H2.
```

and it gives me like

```
1 goal
t : Type
x, y, z : t
l, j : list t
Hnm1 : x = z
H : y :: l = j
H2 : j = z :: l
H3 : z :: j = z :: z :: l
______________________________________(1/1)
j = j -> x = y
```

I think since `j = j` is always true, so I can always have `x = y`. However, when I use `simpl`, I can no further simplify the goal.

So, is there any solution to make coq accept that `j = j -> x = y`?

Comment: Yes, but you have to prove that x=y given the hypothesis in the context (= "above the line").

the hypothesis j=j doesnt help as it contains no information about x and y. You can get rid of it for instance by using `intro Hj.` which moves it into the context.

Next you have to use the other equalities in the context to rewrite your goal into something trivially true like x=x.   Can you see how to do that?

Comment: Btw, I think there is a misunderstanding. It is _not the case_ that from assuming a true statement like j=j you can derive that x=y for any x and y.

Comment: I think I understood. In `j = j -> x = y` I actually want to prove `x = y` from nothing. Since forall y, `y = y` is true. If I have a theorem which tolds me `forall j x y, j = j -> x = y`, I can then prove x = y. However, this theorem must not exist.

Comment: Hmm, well... Back to your task, you want to show `x=y`, and you know (in the context) that `x = z /\ y::l = j /\ j = z::l`.  Can you use this information to deduce that `x=y`?   either way, it doesn not help you to also assume that `j = j` because that is trivially true (by the definition of `=`.

Comment: I have managed to solve it by introducing `y = z`. I asked this question because I was confused about the `y = y ->` pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that `simpl` doesnt do that kind of "simplification" of the proof.  `simpl` does things like replacing variables with their definitions (unfolding/folding), beta reduction, etc. but it does not remove hypotheses from the environment.

In this particular case, to "simplify" the goal from `j=j -> x=y` to the new "simpler" goal `x=y`, you can move the antecedent into the context with the tactict `intros`.